# creating vector with constructor parameter in c++

Tags: c++

Im trying to create 2 vectors of 5 objects (Cats) with a constructor parameter (color).

But i cant find the right syntax.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Cats{
Cats(string color);

};

Cats::Cats(string color){
cout << "Cat " << color << " created" << endl;
}

int main()
{
  vector<Cats> blacks (5, "black");
  vector<Cats> whites (5, "white");
}
```

I want the string of each cat with the color i write to the constructor.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `vector<Cats> blacks(5, Cats("black"));`.

Also see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h/31816096)

Comment: `vector<Cats> blacks(5, string("black"));` would also work.

Comment: why does the constructor runs only ONE time with each vector?

Comment: @PabloLopez Because five `Cats` are created using the copy constructor, from that single `Cats` you constructed manually.

Comment: ok, but how i get the constructor to work for each time? meaning: i will like to show every time a cat is created (cout ...)

Comment: @PabloLopez Provide a custom copy constructor: `Cats(const Cats &other) {...}` and print something in it as well.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will not automatically perform two implicit conversions. Your string literal is a `const char*` which needs to be converted to `std::string` and then to `Cats` before it is the correct type to pass into the `vector` constructor.

You can help the compiler out by performing one of the conversions explicitly:

```
// Pass Cats to the vector constructor, compiler implicitly converts string literal to std::string
vector<Cats> blacks(5, Cats("black"));
// Pass std::string, compiler implicitly converts to Cats before calling the vector constructor
vector<Cats> whites(5, std::string("black"));
```

Alternatively if you're going to be calling code similar to this often, it could be simpler to add a `const char*` constructor to `Cats`:

```
class Cats{
Cats(string color);
Cats(const char* color)
:Cats(std::string(color))
{}
};
```

Your original code would then work.